# .net core 2.0 & Identityserver4 : Cookie Not getting expired after logout

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, session-cookies, identityserver4

I am using identityserver4 for all configured clients with "AccesssTokenType=1" i.e. reference type.

I have one web app hosted for server, and other one for clients.

I used default identityserver settings, which generated two cookie, one for session Id "idsrv.session", and other one for authentication "idsrv".

In logout I do signout

```
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityServerConstants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme);
```

however it gives error when I call with "idsrv.session"
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityServerConstants.DefaultCheckSessionCookieName);

#### Issue / Steps to reproduce the problem

1st Iteration : Login on my client website which redirects to my identityserver application. I now interceprt the request and response using "Burp Suite". I copy the complete response which has redirect URL's and cookie details.

I signout/logout from client website.

2nd Iteration : I tried login again, and intercepted the request and response using Burp Suite, by passing wrong credential. While Intercepting the response I just copied the cookies from previous request (which was successful in my first iteration), and observe that identityserver has successfully validated the user using the cookie value, ignoring the wrong credentials in this iteration.

Even I tried invalidating and deleting cookies in my signout/logout method, but looks like identityserver still recognises it as the valid ones.

Comment: It's not clear which cookie you override and what you expect in connection to reference token validation. If you would like to invalidate a reference **access token** on logout, that should work, yes, but it has nothing to do with **Identity token** persisted in a cookie.And to avoid sniffing, just require SSL as required by the protocol.

Comment: Hi @d_f, whatever cookie name we configure, the values were not getting expired by .net core framework, not even by signout.

Comment: Yeh, that's something I was thinking about -- the nature of the cookie-based auth: unless you do not persist something you can compare with, you can't invalidate the cookie. But, once again, that's **not** about reference access token invalidation, where you persist you token in the server side store and can invalidate it anytime.

Answer (score 1):

Brock Allen directed me to the corrrect solution. According to him :

*This is the real issue you're asking about -- when you signout, you want the cookie to no longer be valid, even in the scenario when it's stolen and replayed. This is not something IdentityServer can address, because we use Microsoft's cookie authentication to achieve signin. You would have to fix this by changing the default usage of their component. You can do it by implementing "server-side cookie" (a term that I dislike) by implementing an ITicketStore: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationOptions.cs#L136*

Details Here 
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2565

Comment: i am also facing the same issue, can you please provide more info about how did you fixed with IticketStore